# how to bring my recursive function to work

Tags: typescript

I am now debugging a recursive function, but I dont know what is wrong with my code.

My recursive function looks like this:

```
  public findParent(parentId: number, node: any): any {
    if (node !== undefined && node.id === parentId) {
      return node;
    } else {
      if (node.predicates && node.predicates.length > 0) {
        for (const element in node.predicates) {
          if (node.predicates[element].predicates !== undefined && node.predicates[element].predicates.length > 0) {
            return this.findParent(parentId, node.predicates[element]);
          } else {
            continue;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and node object looks like this:

```
"node": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "level": 0,
        "field": "",
        "op": "AND",
        "parentId": null,
        "predicates": [
          {
            "field": "",
            "predicates": [],
            "level": 1,
            "parentId": 0,
            "id": 1.1,
            "op": ""
          },
          {
            "field": "",
            "predicates": [
              {
                "field": "",
                "predicates": [
                  {
                    "field": "",
                    "predicates": [],
                    "level": 3,
                    "parentId": 2.4,
                    "id": 4.5
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "",
                    "predicates": [],
                    "level": 3,
                    "parentId": 2.4,
                    "id": 4.7
                  }
                ],
                "level": 2,
                "parentId": 1.2,
                "id": 2.4,
                "op": "AND"
              },
              {
                "field": "",
                "predicates": [
                  {
                    "field": "",
                    "predicates": [],
                    "level": 3,
                    "parentId": 2.5,
                    "id": 3.7
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "",
                    "predicates": [],
                    "level": 3,
                    "parentId": 2.5,
                    "id": 4.3
                  }
                ],
                "level": 2,
                "parentId": 1.2,
                "id": 2.5,
                "op": "AND"
              },
              {
                "field": "",
                "predicates": [],
                "level": 2,
                "parentId": 1.2,
                "id": 3.1
              },
              {
                "field": "",
                "predicates": [],
                "level": 2,
                "parentId": 1.2,
                "id": 3.4
              }
            ],
            "level": 1,
            "parentId": 0,
            "id": 1.2,
            "op": "AND"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

What I expected is, if I give a parent Id into the function, I want to get complete object and his sub/child object(s)

for example, if parentId is: 2.5,

```
              {
                "field": "",
                "predicates": [
                  {
                    "field": "",
                    "predicates": [],
                    "level": 3,
                    "parentId": 2.5,
                    "id": 3.7
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "",
                    "predicates": [],
                    "level": 3,
                    "parentId": 2.5,
                    "id": 4.3
                  }
                ],
                "level": 2,
                "parentId": 1.2,
                "id": 2.5,
                "op": "AND"
              },
```

will be returned.

But now this function is not working

Comment: What is the problem specifically? Does the function not work at all, or it returns a different result than expected?

Comment: I got the diffrent result than expected. I got only the right result, if the parent id = 1.1 is.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is that you return from recursion without checking if the recursive call found a solution. To better understand this, consider this [image: graph of nodes] Your algorithm goes like this: `0 -> 1.1 -> 1.2 -> 2.4`. Now it iterates over `2.4`'s predicates. None of them has predicates, so the call returns back to `1.2`. Now, notice that it was also call which is immediately returned (`return this.findParent(parentId, node.predicates[element]);`), so the algorithm returns further, never checking any of `2.4`'s siblings. In other words, the algorithm returns directly to the root after reaching a node which has only leaf children. I hope this is somewhat clear.

Also, why are you checking a node's children instead of just calling the recursion for the node? Is that intended? I've tested it for `parentId = 1.1` and it also return `undefined` because the node has no children.
Also, `for ... of` is much better than `for ... in` when you iterate over array.

Cheers!